# DAX - Data only populating when I use slicers

Tags: powerbi, dax, datefilter

I want to return count of employees on a table visual without having to use date filters. But count only appears when I move the date slicer.

[date filter selected on slicer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voNjv.png)
[no date filters selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEBFr.png)

Here are my calculations:
SelectedMinDateStart = CALCULATE( MIN('HR Calendar'[FirstDayOfMonth]), ALLSELECTED('HR Calendar'))
--Returns date that is first of the month because data is captured at first day of the month.

Starting Roster Active Employee =

/*VAR StartDate = MeasuresTable[SelectedMinDate]*/

VAR StartDateBegin = MeasuresTable[SelectedMinDateStart]

RETURN

```
CALCULATE (

    DISTINCTCOUNT('Employee Data Snapshot'[Employee]),



         'Employee Data Snapshot'[SnapshotDate] = StartDateBegin)
```

--Returns count of employees

I am expecting the counts on the Starting Roster to appear regardless of date filters selected; populating all dates on table with expected counts.